# What are the software bits involved in display settings change I plug a new display

Tags: display, system-settings

So, the question is almost in the title: what is the process that makes my display settings change automatically when I plug an external display to my laptop ?

Comment: 1) Your question is about a beta version, which is regarded off-topic here. 2) The display change is not docking specific, but just general when you attach an external display. If that's indeed the case, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been fixed by an update of xserver-xorg-video-intel (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1505695).

So it seems hotplug management of displays goes that way:

1. X server driver detects a new monitor. See `man intel` for example, which says

   ```
   Option "HotPlug" "boolean"

     This option controls whether the driver  automatically  notifies
     applications when monitors are connected or disconnected.    

     default: enabled
   ```
2. this information goes through `randr` to inform applications of the event
3. applications listening to randr can then take action: specifically, `gnome-settings-daemon`(*) listens to these events, and will change the settings accordingly, using the informations saved in `~/.config/monitors.xml`

(*) see [gsd-xrandr-manager.c](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/xrandr/gsd-xrandr-manager.c)